# Buffer contains executable data or not? C++ MSDN

Tags: c++, kernel

I am new to MSDN development (C++). I wanted to know if there is any function or API to check if a buffer in kernel is executable or not.

Answer (score 0):

It depends upon which type of *kernel* you are working with.  I presume MSDN means windows; there is a little trove of example programs from a windows internals book here https://github.com/zodiacon/WindowsInternals that may show some specifics.

In general, or at least UNIX derived systems, there is a linkage between a physical page and the *object + offset* it belongs to.  In the case of executable, or text, pages, it is always a file-cache type object.  Typically this object has a collection of mappings, some of which your offset will belong to.  Each mapping has associated permissions; so if you find a mapping with executable permission that corresponds to your page, then it is executable.

In summary:

```
(physical page) -> (object, offset)
(object, offset) ->> (mapping)
(mapping) -> (permission)
```